# How to ensure only one video plays at a time in React application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, next.js, video-streaming

I'm building a React application where I have multiple video components rendered dynamically. I want to ensure that only one video plays at a time, and when a new video starts playing, the previously playing video should pause.

I have a **`RenderVideoSources`** component that maps over an array of video sources and renders individual **`VideoPlayer`** components for each source. Here's a simplified version of my code structure:

```
// RenderVideoSources.tsx
import { useState } from "react";
import type { Source } from "../page";
import VideoPlayer from "./video-player";

export interface RenderVideoSourceTypes<T = unknown> extends Source {
  key?: T;
}

const audioPlayer = () => <></>;

const RenderVideoSources = (props: RenderVideoSourceTypes, index: any) => {
  const component: { [component: string]: React.ElementType<any> } = {
    audio: audioPlayer,
    video: VideoPlayer,
  };

  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState();

  const Component = component[props.type];

  const handlePlayEvent = (currentIndex: any) => {
    setActiveIndex(currentIndex);
    return;
  };

  if (props.type === "video") {
    return (
      <div
        className="flex justify-center items-center"
        key={props.key || index}
      >
        <div className="w-3/4 py-4">
          <Component
            source={props.src}
            isPlaying={activeIndex === index}
            onPlay={() => handlePlayEvent(index)}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  // return <Component key={props.key || index} src={props.src} />;
};

export default RenderVideoSources;
```

And here's the **`VideoPlayer`** component:

```
// VideoPlayer.tsx
"use client";

import {
  MediaCanPlayDetail,
  MediaCanPlayEvent,
  MediaPlayer,
  MediaPlayerInstance,
  MediaProvider,
  MediaViewType,
  Poster,
} from "@vidstack/react";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

import { VideoLayout } from "../layout/video-layout";

import "@vidstack/react/player/styles/default/theme.css";

import styles from "@/app/styles/player.module.css";

export interface VideoPlayerProps {
  source: string;
  isPlaying: boolean;
  onPlay: () => void;
}

const VideoPlayer = ({ isPlaying, source, onPlay }: VideoPlayerProps) => {
  const videoRef = useRef<MediaPlayerInstance>(null);

  const [src, setSrc] = useState("");
  const [viewType, setViewType] = useState<MediaViewType>("unknown");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (source) setSrc(source);
    if (videoRef.current) {
      if (isPlaying) {
        videoRef.current.play();
      } else {
        videoRef.current.pause();
      }
    }
  }, [source, isPlaying]);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      setSrc("");
      setViewType("unknown");
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {src && (
        <MediaPlayer
          className={`${styles.player} media-player`}
          title="Sprite Fight"
          src={src}
          crossOrigin
          playsInline
          onPlay={onPlay}
          // paused={isPlaying}
          ref={videoRef}
        >
          <MediaProvider>
            {viewType === "video" && (
              <Poster
                className={`${styles.poster} vds-poster`}
                src="https://image.mux.com/VZtzUzGRv02OhRnZCxcNg49OilvolTqdnFLEqBsTwaxU/thumbnail.webp?time=268&width=1200"
                alt="Girl walks into campfire with gnomes surrounding her friend ready for their next meal!"
              />
            )}
          </MediaProvider>
          <VideoLayout thumbnails="https://image.mux.com/VZtzUzGRv02OhRnZCxcNg49OilvolTqdnFLEqBsTwaxU/storyboard.vtt" />
        </MediaPlayer>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoPlayer;
```

I'm struggling with implementing the logic inside the **`handlePlayEvent`** function to achieve the desired behavior. How can I ensure that only one video plays at a time and others pause when a new video starts playing?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!